# Generate Avro classes with openapi generator

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm currently unsure whether openapi generator can really do that. Can "only" the avro schemas be generated or also the Java classes directly?
This is not entirely clear from the [documentation](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/avro-schema.md).

"packageName: package for generated classes (where supported)". I set the packageName in the maven plugin generator, but then I just see the changes in to the schema namespace. No Java Class is generated.

Or do I also need the `<artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>` for the java class generation?